# Python islice is reading the same lines

Tags: python, readfile, readlines

I have a big log-file (> 1GB) which should be analysed, so I wrote a python-program. I have used `islice` so I could read the file in chunks (10,000 lines) so my server won't run out of memory.

I've looked up some `islice` solutions on stackoverflow and implemented one, but the program doesn't work as expected because isclice is reading the same lines every time (but stops correctly after reading the whole file...). I can't use `with open` because it comes with python 2.5, I have python 2.4...

My code looks like:

```
    n = 100000;     # n lines
    inf = open(fn, "r")
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(inf, n))
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        out_fn = produce_clean_logfile(next_n_lines)
        a, t = main(out_fn)
        send_log(a,t)
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Regards, John.

Comment: I tried with the islice from itertools and it works.
So your islice implementaion is wrong, you should post it if you want help.

Comment: On top of my script I wrote `from itertools import islice` ... or what do you mean? My `islice` code is in my question-text...

Comment: you are right, there has to be another problem. i've tested it with a dumb 20-line-file and it works, so i have to search at another place! thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import islice
n = 2;     # n lines
fn = "myfile"
inf = open(fn, "r")
while True:
    next_n_lines = list(islice(inf, n))
    if not next_n_lines:
        break
    print next_n_lines
```

works for me on python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 => I can see the lines displayed in order.

The error certainly comes from your other functions, could you update your question?

Comment: you are right, there has to be another problem. i've tested it with a dumb 20-line-file and it works, so i have to search at another place! thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use *groupby* for this

```
from itertools import groupby, count
with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:
    groups = groupby(datafile, key=lambda k, line=count(): next(line)//10000)
    for k, group in groups:
        for line in group:
            ...
```